# Get parameters JSON Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am having this POST request:

```
app/controllers/videogames_controller.rb:10:in `search'
Started POST "/videogames/search" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-09-04 10:39:10 +0200
Processing by VideogamesController#search as JSON
Parameters: {"user"=>{"param"=>"FIFA"}, "videogame"=>{}}
```

and the following controller:

```
def search
   @p = Videogame.where(name: params[:param])
   render :status => 200, :json => { :data =>  @p}
end

def videogame_params
   params.permit(:user, :param)
end
```

What I am trying to do is to send a string to the rails backend (in this case FIFA), so to make a query in the database and to return some objects.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to get the string "FIFA" from the parameters, in order to make the query with it. If I use params[:params] I get a NULL value.

Comment: If you look at the `params` in your request, the value you are looking for `FIFA` is associated with key `param` which is a child to `user`. So you should be trying to do `params[:user][:param]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@p = Videogame.where(name: params[:user][:param])
```